# How to create Complex Form, similar to Nintex in SharePoint Online?

Tags: sharepoint-online, workflow, migration, form, nintex

What do you recommend to use in SharePoint Online to create Complex Forms? Right now we are using Nintex On-Premise to all of current workflows and since we already have SPO we need to move/migrate our Workflows to Online.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the long run, in SharePoint online, the recommendation is PowerApps for forms development and Power Automate (Microsoft Flow) for the workflows.

Having said these, for SharePoint Online, there are two types of forms and workflow version available from Nintex:

- Nintex Office 365 (separate license needed)
- Nintex Cloud (part of the office 365 tenant, no separate license is needed) - it is like Microsoft Flow and PowerApps which has lots of third party connectors, using that we can connect to any other third application, update or new releases come every two weeks.

To conclude, you can have **PowerApps**, **PowerAutomate**, and **Nintex Cloud** - based on the needs you can choose any of these tools.

Comment: Hi we reached out to Nintex and their cloud platform and their pricing is too high , did you developed work around like creating custom html / spfx as power apps is not good for complex form design as it is for mobile.

Comment: Hi @BizApps - Just wondering, are sure you enquired for Nintex cloud because there are two products for SharePoint online - 1) Nintex 365 2)Nintex Cloud - as per my knowledge nintex cloud is the part of Office 365 tenant license, so if you have tenant, that will be part of that. Coming to your second question - yes, using the combination of SPFx and React we can develop any complex form but will be expensive as it needs purely development works - I have not done, but it is possible using SPFx and React.

Answer (score 1):

Just like Habibur said, if you want to create complex forms, PowerApps and Power Automate(MS flow) will be an option. You can consider them as the new and much more powerful InfoPath and workflow, highly integrated with SharePoint Online.

For migration you may better to contact with Nintex. Per my knowledge there are no tools to migrate Nintex workflows to Power Automate. You may need to keep using Nintex products if you do not want to re-construct all workflows and forms.

Introduction About PowerApps and Power Automate:

https://powerapps.microsoft.com/en-us/automate-processes/

https://products.office.com/en-us/business/microsoft-powerapps